# Running a polling job in a windows service with TPL

Tags: windows-services, task-parallel-library, task, long-polling

In the past I have used timer to do polling job that retrieves the data from one database and insert into another after processing the data. I'm trying to write this with **TPL** (Task Parallel Library).

Is the following code with `Task.Delay`, the efficient way to run a polling job in a **window service** with TPL?

When I said 'efficient' it means it doesn't consume more resources from the OS neither wasting. [Jeffrey Ritcher](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/author/jeffreyr) in this Wintellect video on [Thread Fundamentals](https://wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch?videoId=thread-fundamentals) strongly discourages to use `Thread.Sleep`. His argument is that an app should not hold a thread if it is not using so other apps or the same app can use it from the thread pool.

I assume `Task.Delay` internally doing a `Thread Sleep` so I assume it is inefficient.

Another requirement is that this job also has to run every minute and overlapping should be avoided.

```
class Program
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private Task _etlTask;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _etlTask = Task.Run(
            async () =>
                    {
                        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

                        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            await etlJob.Run(); // An ETL Job to read from DB to update another DB

                            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), token);
                        }
                    });
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        try
        {
            _etlTask.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle exeption
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use the `Delay` instead of `Timer`. Mark long running task as `LongRunning`

Comment: Do you mean, use ```Timer``` instead of ```Delay```?

Comment: Yes, do not use `Delay` for such tasks

Comment: Can you please explain the reason?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your comment. Are you saying my code looks okay except that don't use ```Task.Delay```? I have it to poll only every minute.

Comment: `Delay` is a task, and it's not guaranteed to start exactly every minute, it may be postponed for some time, especially if there are a lot of other tasks. You should use the `Threading.Timer`, which is right for such cases. Also, mark your `Task` as long running

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code looks fine.

> This job has to run every minute and overlapping should be avoided.

The way it's currently structured, it has a *minute of delay* between executions, which is not quite the same thing as "running every minute". If that's good enough for you, I'd just keep it as-is.

Comment: I added some comments to what I meant by efficiency. Your feedback is appreciated.